# What do these MediaPlayer errorcodes mean?

Tags: android, media-player

The onErrorListener of my MediaPlayer did return what=1, extra -1004 and extra -1007.

BTW, where can I find a list of these error codes?

Answer (score 0):

Usually I refer to [pvmi/pvmf/include/pvmf_return_codes.h](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/opencore/+/master/pvmi/pvmf/include/pvmf_return_codes.h)
But I didnt find extra -1004 and -1007.

Under what conditions those errors came out?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I try to play an MP3 file from my own website that needs user authentication. If I fetch HTML pages I do set an Authorization header. Now I set mediaPlayer.setDataSource to a file on this website and I think this authorization is required here too. I bet these codes have something to do with it but I can't find a way to set an "authorization header" to an URI that I feed into MediaPlayer. So I was looking for these codes first to find out the exact error.

Comment: as per the developer pages - what=1,MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN. as per your comment due to lack of authorization Mediaplayer seems doesn't detect the source.